# Add one more inner array if I have more values to insert in my 2D Array, Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, kivy

I'm having some logic-issues while working with a multidimensional Array.
I want to create a 2D Array where each one of its inner-arrays can have 8 elements in, if the amount of elements is greater than the amount of inner-arrays I need to then create an extra one and add the rest of the elements in the array that was created.

This is what I have so far:

**NOTE**: variable "data" will contain any amount of values I get from a SELECT query that I do to my DB, for this example lets say that I have 11 categories.

```
category_list = ListProperty()

data = ['Category0', 'Category1', 'Category2', 'Category3', 'Category4', 
         'Category5', 'Category6', 'Category7', 'Category8', 'Category9',
         'Category10']

for i in range(1):
  self.category_list.append([])
    for j in range(8):
      if i*8+j >= len(data):
        break
      self.category_list[i].append(data[i*8+j])
```

**This is what I will get**: [['Category0', 'Category1', 'Category2', 'Category3', 'Category4', 'Category5', 'Category6', 'Category7']]

Which is nice because it only saves 8 elements in my first inner array, I know that if I increase the range from **1** to **2** the rest of the categories that I have in 'data' will be in the second inner-array

```
[
['Category0', 'Category1', 'Category2', 'Category3', 
'Category4', 'Category5', 'Category6', 'Category7'], 
['Category8', 'Category9', 'Category10']
]
```

That's cool, that's what I need (**sorta**). The idea is to generate a new inner-array if it is needed without modifying the range manually.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use while loops instead of for loops, that way it will just keep looping until a certain condition is met rather than a fixed number of times:

```
data = ['Category0', 'Category1', 'Category2', 'Category3', 'Category4','Category5', 'Category6', 'Category7', 'Category8', 'Category9','Category10', 'Category11', 'Category12','Category13','Category14','Category15','Category16','Category17','Category18','Category19','Category20','Category21','Category22','Category23','Category24','Category25','Category26']


category_list = []

n = 0
while n < len(data):
    lim = min(n+8,len(data))
    cats = []
    while n < lim:
        cats.append(data[n])
        n += 1
    category_list.append(cats)

print(category_list)
```

output

```
[['Category0', 'Category1', 'Category2', 'Category3', 'Category4', 'Category5', 'Category6', 'Category7'], ['Category8', 'Category9', 'Category10', 'Category11', 'Category12', 'Category13', 'Category14', 'Category15'], ['Category16', 'Category17', 'Category18', 'Category19', 'Category20', 'Category21', 'Category22', 'Category23'], ['Category24', 'Category25', 'Category26']]
```